# How to customize navigation bar in swiftui

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

How to implement this navigation bar in **swiftui** .it is looks like default .largeTitle but have different height and right button
[Navigation as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXH4q.png)

Comment: To add navigation buttons, you can check this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607175/navigation-stuff-in-swiftui

Comment: @swifty but i don't want just a button [that what i need](https://imgur.com/a/a5CntwR)

Comment: @swifty the background color may not be important but the arrangement of the elements is important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best solution I could come up with. You basically set the title generated by the navigation bar to an empty string, and construct your own title view in the leading view of the navigation bar.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("NavigationBarView")
                .navigationBarTitle("") //Set title to none so that it won't put the bottom title
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    //This is your made up title, put in the leading view so it is up top aligned with the plus button
                    Text("Navigation Bar").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    //This is the plus button, on the right side, aka trailing view
                    , trailing: Button(action: {

                    }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    })
            )

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me, but a margin of unknown height appeared to me. How to remove it? [red line is bad margin](https://imgur.com/a/tAocDDe)

Comment: and I don’t clearly understand why you use two buttons

Comment: @VipFilStar, sorry, was my mistake to use two buttons, just copied and pasted in the wrong place, and the second button was the label of the actual button. I have edited the answer to show the image as a label to the button.

Comment: but what about margin? I wrote about this in a previous post.

Comment: You can add an offset of -100 points on the y axis for the view that contains that text. This should eliminate that margin.